# Show several Local Notifications without creating new one

Tags: ios, swift, notifications

My scenario that I need to show the first Local Notification using Swift and then using the same identifier add another Local Notification, but without showing it as a popup in iOS device. So basically the flow would be like this:

**Starting upload...** <-- Show on the screen and adds to the Tray bar

**Uploading photos...** <-- Does not shows on the screen, but clears all the notifications and add another one in Tray bar silently (or changes previous one)

**Uploading data...** <-- Same as Uploading photos...

**Finished uploading...** <-- Same as Uploading photos...

Tried different ways, on Android it is not hard to do that, but iOS makes everything hard to do, is it even possible? :)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The reason it works on Android is because the "state showing" notifications are very Android thing. iOS is not designed for this kind of stuff because you almost never do something in the background of an app that also needs to be reflected to the user while user is outside of an app. So the real answer to your question is no. In iOS environment it is not possible to simulate Android way of showing status changes in a notification.